# How do I default the LFS checkbox to checked in the TortoiseGit Git clone Dialog box?

Tags: tortoisegit, git-lfs

I have a repository that uses git lfs. Each time I clone, I need to remember to tick the LFS checkbox.

How do I default the LFS checkbox to checked in the TortoiseGit Git clone Dialog box?

I have looked through the registry using RegEdit for LFS and TortoiseGit for an lfs related entry.
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-258###\Software\TortoiseGit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state of the checkbox is not remembered and cannot be set "checked" by default as of TortoiseGit 2.8.